# How can I create dynamic brick/tile-like geometry?

Tags: modifiers, geometry, 3d-printing

I want to create something like this:

[image: Bricks]

The key requirements are:

- Must be actual geometry. I'm going to be 3d printing this, so I don't think using materials will help me here.
- Would like to be able to adjust the width of the gap/grout
- Would like to be able to control the number of/density of bricks to some degree
- Bonus points: would love to be able to add a bit of noise/random rotation to the bricks as a last step

So far what I've been doing is slicing up planes with the knife tool, insetting the faces, extruding them, and then using a boolean to cut them all into individual bricks. But the manual slicing is tedious (especially if I want to make 100 different versions of this), and I can't really go back and modify any of the parameters after I'm done. Again, I will be 3D printing this... so I'd like to be able to create the mesh, print it, check for printing problems, and then go back and tune/adjust the mesh easily.

Comment: Upon doing a bit more digging, it looks like there are (or at least were) a number of plugins that might help: jarch vis, blockwall, drystone, and masonry. Looks like many of them are old/unsupported though.

Answer (score 2):

The **Wall Factory** is a step in the right direction, and it's already included in blender.

To activate, go to **User Preferences** (Ctrl + Alt + U). Then go to the **Add-ons** tab and enable **Add Mesh: Extra Objects**.

To add a new wall, press **Shift + A** and then go to **Mesh > Extras > Wall Factory**

[image]

[image]

However, it doesn't look like I can go back and modify things like brick size or grout width after I've created the wall.